# Spring 2.5 MVC:BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'EmpPersonalBean' available as request attribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I got error "BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'EmpPersonalBean' available as request attribute" when the logged successfully in the application using Spring MVC,JDBC(Version 2.5). I forward loginpage into jsp/UserPage.jsp

My folder struture is

```
WEB-ROOT      
  |__JSP  (folder)            
      |__user   (sub folder)                    
           |_userdashboardpage.jsp      
  |__loginpage.jsp  (In Webroot)    
  |__web.xml
```

Controller :UserController Class

In this controller called onsubmit method after successfully i redirected the page.check the below code snippet

```
public ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,Object command,BindException errors) throws Exception {       
         String username="",password="";
         username=request.getParameter("username");
         password=request.getParameter("password");
        UserBean ubean=null;
        HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
         try{
             ubean=userservice.chkUsername(username,password);
             System.out.println("Information"+ubean.getUsername());
             }catch(DataException ex){
             ex.printStackTrace();

             //throw ex;
              }
        session.setAttribute("User",ubean);
        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView(("forward:jsp/UserPage.jsp"));
        return  mv;
    }
```

In the UserPage.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" import="com.aims.bean.*" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tld/c.tld" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>AAI</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="EmpPersonalBean" action="userpage.htm">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Welcome <%=((UserBean)session.getAttribute("User")).getUsername()%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Department</td>
        <td><form:select path="deparment">
                      <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />
                      <form:options items="${deparmentList}" />
                       </form:select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tr>
</table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the userpage, trying to loaded deparment list using referenceData method from UserDBBoardController.

```
public class UserDBBoardController  extends SimpleFormController{
    private static final Log log=new Log(UserDBBoardController.class);
    private UserService userservice;
    public void setUserservice(UserService userservice) {
        this.userservice = userservice;
    }
    public UserDBBoardController(){
        setCommandClass(EmpPersonalBean.class);
        setCommandName("EmpPersonalBean");

    }
    protected Map referenceData(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        log.info("UserDBBoardController======================referenceData");
        Map referenceData = new HashMap();
        Map deparementList=new HashMap();
        deparementList=userservice.getDeparmentList();
        referenceData.put("deparmentList",deparementList);
        return referenceData;

    }
}
```

Dispatcher Servlet.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props><prop key="/loginpage.htm">UserController</prop>
        <prop key="/userpage.htm">UserDBBoardController</prop></props>
    </property>
    </bean>
    <import resource="application-context.xml"/>
    <bean id="User" class="com.aims.bean.UserBean" scope="session" />
    <bean id="UserController" class="com.epis.controllers.UserController"  >
    <property name="userservice" ref="userservice"/>
    <property name="sessionForm"><value>true</value></property>
    <property name="commandName"><value>UserBean</value></property>
    <property name="commandClass"><value>com.aims.bean.UserBean</value></property>
    <property name="validator"><ref bean="userformValidator"/></property> 
    <property name="formView"><value>loginpage</value></property>
    <property name="successView"><value>UserPage</value></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="UserDBBoardController" class="com.epis.controllers.UserDBBoardController"  >
    <property name="userservice" ref="userservice"/>
    <property name="sessionForm"><value>true</value></property>
    <property name="commandName"><value>EmpPersonalBean</value></property>
    <property name="commandClass"><value>com.aims.bean.EmpPersonalBean</value></property>

    </bean>
```

This error message came from loading of deparment list in userpage?.How to resolve this issue?.Please help.

Another doubt is Why spring MVC provides too many types of controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using This constructor for ModelAndView that also accepts Model Name and Model Object.
[http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html#ModelAndView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html#ModelAndView%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: I given the name and object in modelAndView Contructor.Its working fine.But my department list is not populated.why?